# Any models for text to json

Tags: deep-learning, natural-language-processing, seq2seq

There are many sequence to sequence (seq2seq) models and end to end models, like text to sql. I was wondering are there any text to json deep learning models?

For example:

Text

```
"Switch on the computer".
```

JSON:

```
{"actions":["switch on"], "object":"computer"}
```

Another Example:

Text:

```
"Lower the heater temperature to 25 degrees and before that play music for one hour".
```

JSON:

```
 {"actions": ["lower the heater temperature","play the music"],"order":[1,0]}
```

Note that JSON has different or some additional elements depending on the text. This is different from regular seq2seq models. Any suggestions on which models to use? Thank you!!

Comment: You may be asking for a [semantic parsing model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_parsing)

Comment: Thank you, it looks something close to what I've been looking for.

Comment: @tiredandboreddev did you ever find anything? Also looking for something similar.

Comment: For my purpose, I could find seq2seq models work to some extent...